# Applying style through hover using JavaScript doesn't work with class

Tags: javascript

I want to apply a style to an element when hovering over another element in a different parent `div`.

The classes are `lvcontainer` and `rvcontainer` and when I hover over `lvcontainer`, `rvcontainer` will be set to `display: block`.

I'm trying to make a multidimensional drop menu like blackberry navigation.

```js
var lvcontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('lvcontainer');
var rvcontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('rvcontainer');

for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  lvcontainer[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    rvcontainer[i].style.display = "block";
  }, false);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

#container {
  display: table;
}

#lcontainer {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

#rcontainer {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.rvcontainer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="lcontainer">
    <div class="lvcontainer">
      Country
    </div>
    <div class="lvcontainer">
      Genre
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rcontainer">
    <div class="rvcontainer">
      Japan
      <br> Korea
      <br> American
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="rvcontainer">
      Comedy
      <br> Mystery
      <br> Horror
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use CSS `:hover` as `.lvcontainer:hover { display: block; }`.

Comment: @Tushar so what the complete selector? `.lvcontainer:hover .rvcontainer`? i already try in css but dont't work.

Comment: It should be `.rcontainer:hover rvcontainer { display: block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues but you can do what you want by looping through and protecting your index.

The below assumes there will always be the same number of lvcontainer and rvcontainer

```js
var lvcontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('lvcontainer');
var rvcontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('rvcontainer');

for (i = 0; i < lvcontainer.length; i++) {  // loop to the length
  (function(protectedIndex) {               // protect the index so clicks won't use last increment of i

    // show
    lvcontainer[protectedIndex].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      rvcontainer[protectedIndex].style.display = "block"; 
    }, false);

    // hide
    lvcontainer[protectedIndex].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      rvcontainer[protectedIndex].style.display = "none";
    }, false);
  })(i);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

#container {
  display: table;
}

#lcontainer {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

#rcontainer {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.rvcontainer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="lcontainer">
    <div class="lvcontainer">
      Country
    </div>
    <div class="lvcontainer">
      Genre
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rcontainer">
    <div class="rvcontainer">
      Japan
      <br> Korea
      <br> American
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="rvcontainer">
      Comedy
      <br> Mystery
      <br> Horror
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After your comment, I would restructure your html to be a bit more semantically correct:

```css
#container ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#lcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.lvcontainer {
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.1em 0.1em;
}

.rvcontainer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.lvcontainer:hover>.rvcontainer {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="lcontainer">
    <li class="lvcontainer">
      Country
      <ul class="rvcontainer">
        <li>Japan</li>
        <li>Korea</li>
        <li>American</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lvcontainer">
      Genre
      <ul class="rvcontainer">
        <li>Comedy</li>
        <li>Mystery</li>
        <li>Horror</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pete

Comment: Pete why i cant hover to rvcontainer? i can't click them. it will dissapper if i mouseout from lvcontainer.

Comment: @daivdrush because rvcontainer is not a child of lv container - I think you need to structure your html properly and use ul and li.  Give me 10 minutes and I'll add a better answer

Comment: i add some css rule but the rule i think stack with javascript. i remove hide javascript. with `.rvcontainer:not(:hover){display: none;} .rvcontainer:hover{display:block;} .lvcontainer:hover{display: block}`

Comment: @daivdrush have a look at the updated answer - it's probably the better way to do things, then you do not have to rely on js.  If you want the 2nd menu to be positioned on the same line as the the hovered item, move relative position from ul to li

Comment: now new problem arise if i use ul ways. container background-color not auto fill. cause rvcontainer use position absolute;

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last 2 comments, but if the ul doesn't work, then all you need to do is change the js in the first snippet so that the display none is only applied when you want it to be applied.  You should really ask a new question about it though as this question has been answered and your initial problem solved - link this question in your new one as background to your problem

Comment: Sory i'm too fast to press accept answer when first answer. but i realize when i arleady press accept. the rv container can;t be hover. what the use menu navigator if the menu can't focus or even to click?** I'm trying to make a multidimensional drop menu like blackberry navigation.** thats my point in question.  and ul ways fix something but in other it arise new problem like background-color not follow parent. padding can't be use. what the use navi if no background-color?

Comment: ok unaccept if you want but this answers your above question - how do I get hover to show corresponding block - your new question changes the above question completely - how do I get block to stay shown when I leave original hover and move into new shown block

Comment: ow ok, i will stick to div problem with javascript. ul ways too many problem arise. i just need to open new post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the cleaner solution but you can try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: auto;
    }

    #container {
        display: table;
    }

    #lcontainer {
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        display: table-cell;
    }

    #rcontainer {
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .rvcontainer-c,.rvcontainer-g {
        display: none;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="lcontainer">
        <div class="lvcontainer-c">
            Country
        </div>
        <div class="lvcontainer-g">
            Genre
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rcontainer">
        <div class="rvcontainer-c">
            Japan
            <br> Korea
            <br> American
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="rvcontainer-g">
            Comedy
            <br> Mystery
            <br> Horror
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

var lvcontainerC = document.getElementsByClassName('lvcontainer-c');
var rvcontainerC = document.getElementsByClassName('rvcontainer-c');

lvcontainerC[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    rvcontainerC[0].style.display = "block";
}, false);
lvcontainerC[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    rvcontainerC[0].style.display = "none";
}, false);

var lvcontainerG = document.getElementsByClassName('lvcontainer-g');
var rvcontainerG = document.getElementsByClassName('rvcontainer-g');
lvcontainerG[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    rvcontainerG[0].style.display = "block";
}, false);
lvcontainerG[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    rvcontainerG[0].style.display = "none";
}, false);


</script>
</html>
```